# (location.origin) results unexpected .js

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to detect if the browser window URL is HTTPS or HTTP:

```
var yourUrl = window.location.origin;
var parse_url = /^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\d+))?  (?:\/([^?#]*))?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$/;
var parts = parse_url.exec( yourUrl );
var result = parts[1]+':'+parts[2]+parts[3]+'/' ;
if (parts[1] === "https") {
HTTPSp('Secure Connection','http://www.mysite.co.uk/images/secure.png','HTTPSp');
alert(result);
stopthisscript();
}
```

The issue I have is that with some websites it displays other URLs within the page, for example if I go to say http://mysite.co.uk, it will display https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ and not http as in the browser address bar?

Is there another, more reliable way in JavaScript of detecting the protocol used within the browser address bar?

Note, I have also used "location.protocol;" with the same results.

Thanks

Comment: Are you executing this within an ad iframe or what? If so, use `window.top.location`

Comment: Its a FireFox SDK project. I have a "main.js" file which is calling an external .js file which has the above code. I could try "window.top.location" and see what happens.